# How a Ruby on Rails developer should start learning Python Django

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django

I want to learn Django for web development. And for Django I need to know Python. I have never coded in Python but after reading discussions and articles on the web I think it wont be a difficult task.

I have been coding in Ruby and using Ruby on Rails from more than past two years. So I can say that I have fairly good knowledge of web development with an MVC framework. How should I go about learning Python and Django? Although it might be very useful but I do not wish to learn any other aspect of Python other than Django.

I am looking for pointers to some tutorials, books, blogs or any other material that can get me started rapidly. It would be very useful if someone could tell me the order in which I should start going through these materials. Should I read a book first or create a sample application or follow some tutorial?

Thanks!

Comment: Python for Programmers might be of help : https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers  
Python for programmers pdf : http://www.aleax.it/goo_py4prog.pdf   
Something similar for Django might be helpful.

Comment: Moving to Python from other languages : https://wiki.python.org/moin/MovingToPythonFromOtherLanguages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official tutorials for [Python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) and [Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) are both good. There are so many freely available books on Python. [Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/) (free) by it's creators is great if you are not satisfied with the tutorial.

Comment: Apparently the 'Django Book' is very out-of-date and is in the process of being open-sourced on github to make it upto-date.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what *I* think will work:

1. Install Python on your machine.
2. Go through any introductory tutorial. Here is one that [works well with most](http://diveintopython.net/toc/index.html).
3. Install Django
4. Go through an [introductory tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).
5. Code.
6. Find someone for feedback. (Mailing list etc)
7. Jump to step 5 (i.e. Repeat)

For 5, you can start with a Inventory based app and basic listing (and an Admin that comes inbuilt with Django). Build over the app by adding XMLHTTP interaction, authentication, authorization, image uploads, e-commerce etc. These amongst others are commonly required skills.

Comment: Closing the feedback loop is critical to learning any new skillset, IMHO.  Find someone who knows more than you to look at what you're doing once you've accomplished something and clue you in to the aspects of what you're doing that aren't idiomatic.

Comment: @karmajunkie: Yes, that is what I meant through 5-7 (Please let me know if it doesn't sound so, I'll edit it)

Comment: no, i think its clear, I intended to echo those thoughts.  I think it was me that was unclear. :)

Answer (score 3):

As you say, it won't be hard--you already know what you're doing, you just have to get used to a slightly different style.

[Dive into Python](http://diveintopython.net/toc/index.html) describes itself as "a Python book for experienced programmers", so that's probably worth a look. But don't spend too long reading--once you can see the basic differences, I'd just start coding, and learn more as you go.