# Python / Django implementation without previous experience with this syntax

Tags: python, django

I am a Web Developer that has a client that would like to have Django implemented into their next interface.

Having never been taught these two languages before, (Python & Django) I took it upon myself to go over the tutorials from start to finish on djangoprojects page. Now I am a visual learner and need more. The scope covered in making a polling app didn't satisfy the knowledge I need.

My question to you is where can I find source code of some Django sites and possibly other material worthy of getting me up to speed.

Thanks

WDH

Comment: everyone learns differently, of course, but I found the poling app tutorials more than enough when I started with django.  I'd suggest you just start writing code, pick an app you want, and start banging away, when you run into specific pain points and questions, I'm sure someone here cna point you in the right direction.

Comment: Django is not a language, it's a framework. It's written entirely in Python.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428555/how-a-ruby-on-rails-developer-should-start-learning-python-django

Comment: is it something in particular that you feel you'd like to learn besides the basics?

Comment: Coming from a strictly XHTML / CSS / PHP background it's just a little more to digest a the moment with deadlines looming.

I am looking for a quick transition to take a regular page that has already been coded to add all the {% include %} and {% block %} statements.

Answer (score 1):

For python, you should take a look at [DiveIntoPython](http://diveintopython.net/toc/index.html).

Regarding Django, you should take a lookt at :

- [The Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) (what you did, if I understood correctly)
- [The Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/)

And I believe that taking a look at how Django works by reading the [source code](http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/) is very interesting, for both your learning in python AND django :)

Comment: DiveIntoPython3 is for python3, which is not the language used by django (django uses python 2.4 - 2.7; though I'd recommend 2.6 or 2.7 if installing now).  In general, Python3 is not compatible with python 2.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#can-i-use-django-with-python-3

Comment: Updated to DiveIntoPython 2 :)

Comment: Yeah, I have Django 2.7 installed with Python 2.7.1 as the backend.

I have completely gone through the tutorials at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I believe you are mixing Django and Python, Python is the programming language, Django is a web framework written in Python. Django lastest version is 1.3

Comment: My bad... yes Django 1.3 is what I am using

Comment: Django version is currently 1.3, not 2.7 :)